# what is meant by hook in spring security?

Tags: java, spring

What is "hook" in Spring security and how is the term "hook" normally defined in programming? I've searched but didn't get a good idea of the meaning while i was going through Stack Overflow. I need some detailed explanation.

Comment: A place to hang custom functionality.

Comment: Hi Dave,Thanks for the reply.Is that a callback function.

Comment: Not in the traditional sense, at least that's not what I'd call it. It's just an extension point.

Comment: As i am a novice couldn't get much about it.Can you please explain me in detail

Answer (score 0):

**This is called *Hooking*.**

> In computer programming, the term hooking covers a range of techniques
>   used to alter or augment the behavior of an operating system, of
>   applications, or of other software components by intercepting function
>   calls or messages or events passed between software
>   components. Code that handles such intercepted
>   function calls, events or messages is called a "hook".

Click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) for its Wikipedia page.